# AWS Beanstalk Application Health Check

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We use Beanstalk to deploy node applications. It works very well. I've created a couple of config files in an .ebextensions directory, to apply configuration info to our apps when we load them up. Again mostly works well. I have one thing that does not, and that is defining the application health check URL. I can't get it to go. One odd thing about it, it seems to be only parameter I have come across so far that has spaces in it, and I'm wondering about that. I have tried enclosing the values in quotes, just to see if that is the problem, but it still doesn't work. Has anyone done this before, and can tell me whether it works, and if there is something syntactical about this that is incorrect? As I said, the rest of the params get set correctly in beanstalk, just the last one doesn't. Note #environment# gets replaced with a grunt script before this gets deployed.

Here's the config file:

```
 option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
     option_name: NODE_ENV
     value: #environment#
   - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
     option_name: NodeVersion
     value: 0.10.10
   - namespace: aws:autoscaling:trigger
     option_name: LowerThreshold
     value: 40
   - namespace: aws:autoscaling:trigger
     option_name: MeasureName
     value: CPUUtilization
   - namespace: aws:autoscaling:trigger
     option_name: UpperThreshold
     value: 60
   - namespace: aws:autoscaling:trigger
     option_name: Unit
     value: Percent
   - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
     option_name: Application Healthcheck URL
     value: /load_balance_test
```

Comment: An update. Amazon told us that yes, that parameter didn't work. They are investigatig.

Comment: Were you ever able to get the option to work properly?

Comment: Haven't gone back and retried in a long time. Just been entering it manually. They have not replied to me about the issue.

Comment: I just tried. It worked for me. Only the format specified in the original question worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Adding this worked for me:

```
# .ebextensions/healthcheckurl.config
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
    option_name: Application Healthcheck URL
    value: /health
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default
    option_name: HealthCheckPath
    value: /health
```

I discovered the second setting by doing `eb config`, which gives a nice overview of environment settings that can be overriden with `option_settings` in `.ebextensions/yet-another.config` files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It was that second option that I couldn't find documented anywhere.

Comment: had the same issues, here is the link to doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentprocess

Answer (score 3):

The spaces in this property name are weird, but it works when used with the alternative shorthand syntax for options:

```
option_settings:

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:
    Application Healthcheck URL: /
```

Answer (score 0):

I use CloudFormation for EB, and in CF the syntax for that parameter is very strange. If that config file works the same as CF, the following string should work for you:

`HTTP:80/load_balance_test`

Comment: That is strange indeed. You'd think they'd follow some kind of norm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/), then just make sure you have spaces in the `name`, and it will work fine:

```
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application"
    name = "Application Healthcheck URL"
    value = "/api/health"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried. It worked for me. Only the format specified in the original question worked for me i.e.,

```
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
    option_name:  Application Healthcheck URL
    value:  /api/v1/health/
```

Answer (score 0):

you also might want to set the health_check_type to ELB instead of default EC2.
this is how I configured mine

```
$ cat .ebextensions/0090_healthcheckurl.config 
Resources:
   AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
     Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
     Properties:
       HealthCheckType: "ELB"
       HealthCheckGracePeriod: "600"
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
    option_name:  Application Healthcheck URL
    value:  /_status
```